How to reduce the compilation time of styles.scss in Angular
My styles.scss imports files as shown in the picture.
styles.scss

Every time I modify the content of one of these imported files, the recompilation takes more than a minute.
I've searched for many related issues and tried modifying webpack and babel configurations, but nothing has helped.
Is there any method that can help me reduce the compilation time, ideally to less than half a minute?

try this. most likely tailwind is taking 95% of your css compilation time
